# TortoiseSVN user guide dead URL?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to follow this tutorial of [TortoiseSVN user guide](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-repo).
I have created the folder "C:\Projects\Widget1" as indicated.
Then, when I want to import project content from the cited URL "https://tardis/svn/screwdriver" I get the following error message "Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://tardis/svn/screwdriver'"
I am waiting for a clarification on the issue to be able to continue the tutorial. I am stuck for now :)
Thanks

Edit:
I realized I've made a mistake in following the user guide steps. Now I am able to checkout a working copy from my local repository, but the working copy folder is empty (as I expect). However, the rest of the user guide hints that I'll be working with files inside the working copy (how ?)

Comment: You should edit your question to eliminate the initial problem that you had and explain the steps you took leading up to where your current confusion is.

Answer (score 0):

Your working copy will only contain files if the repository location you checked out from has files in it. If you're starting with a brand-new repository, you have nothing in the repository to populate the working copy.

The user guide hints that you'll be working with files inside the working copy because it assumes that you've imported an existing project into the repository before checking that working copy. If you skipped over that step, that's why you're seeing nothing.